# Xamarin Forms : App crashing in android 14

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, mobile, mobile-development, android-14

when i clean and rebuild it works fine but when i Build the application in android 14 mobile like google pixel 7 then the application gets installed but crashes after splash screen.

I have added the android 14 sdk and changed the targeted version to android 14. working fine in android 13 or below but crashing in android 14.

If anyone has faced this issue Kindly provide the steps how you have resolved it.

Comment: You can check the [release note](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin#xamarin-releases) about the Xamarin.Forms support. The xamarin have not release the version to support the Android 14.

Comment: Thank you for you reply but in the release notes they have mentioned that It can target API level 34 I.E, Android 14.

Comment: Yes, the Xamarin.Forms will support the Android 14, but the new version has not been released yet.